# Google Fonts not showing Chrome and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, font-face

I'm pulling in the google font code using their include.  Their CSS looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v7/HqHm7BVC_nzzTui2lzQTDfY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot);
  src: local('Oswald Light'), local('Oswald-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v7/HqHm7BVC_nzzTui2lzQTDfY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v7/HqHm7BVC_nzzTui2lzQTDT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Using this I created a css class

```
.oswald {
    font-family: 'Oswald', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
```

Then I use that like this

```
<div class="oswald">text</div>
```

Here's where it gets a little weird.  I'm using Visual Studio so when I debug it locally I see the correct font.  When I put it up on the server it's showing me the Verdana font.  Chrome also shows the wrong front.  Safari and Firefox both show the correct font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've converted Oswald Regular into the necessary `@font-face` formats (TTF, OTF, EOT, SVG, WOFF).

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('Archive/Oswald-Regular.eot');
  src: local('Oswald'), url('Archive/Oswald-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('Archive/Oswald-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Archive/Oswald-Regular.svg#Oswald-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And here is the link to the ZIP archive that contains the converted fonts: http://www.mediafire.com/?9xdr1w9wyvdoh09

Comment: That fixed it for Chrome, any ideas for IE?

Answer (score 0):

I find using the css @import rule a lot more reliable and avoids having to have the 5x formats of fonts required for browser compatibility. Drop this in to the top of your CSS file:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300);
```

PS. This will include: light (`font-weight: 300`), regular (`font-weight: 400`) and bold (`font-weight: 700`) for Oswald.

Comment: That is what I had, I just pasted what their CSS showed here so you could see everything.