# Oswald font not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, font-face, google-font-api

Ok so Bazar (a different font) is working perfectly on Chrome, but for some ODD reason Oswald won't.. I looked at this thread:

[Google Fonts not showing Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227535/google-fonts-not-showing-chrome-and-ie)

The first reply supposedly fixed their problem in Chrome, but it won't work for me. I even linked to the stylesheet THROUGH googlefonts with the  tag in the  Nothing will fix this issue.. and I really need to get it to work on Chrome.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    src: url('core/fonts/oswald/oswald.eot');
    src: local('Oswald'),
    url('core/fonts/oswald/oswald.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('core/fonts/oswald/oswald.woff') format('woff'),
    url('core/fonts/oswald/oswald.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('core/fonts/oswald/oswald.svg#oswald') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
nav .menu a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 1.4em;
}
```

This works on IE8 and up, Firefox, and Opera.. but not on Chrome which is weird because usually IE is the one having issues..

I have tried the @import,  AND this.. ALL options.. and I'm running out. I really prefer NOT to use Javascript just for a font issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, found out that ssl was causing the issue. After setting up ssl to point only to 1 specific folder, the font resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if Oswald font is installed on your system. I yes, than try to uninstall the font and use import Oswald on google font.

I had the same issue and that's what I did and it fixed my problem, maybe it can fixes your problem too. :)